# Style with template is blocking the text in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to create a template for my buttons that have:

- Border corner radius
- Background as gradient
- Change border color on hover

So far I got here:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="aimDark">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,0" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#0e0e0e" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border
                        CornerRadius="4"
                        BorderBrush="#000000"
                        BorderThickness="1">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="#006d23" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#006d23" Offset="0.05" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#00c741" Offset="0.45" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#00c741" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <RenderOptions.EdgeMode>Aliased</RenderOptions.EdgeMode>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Test" Name="btn01" Style="{StaticResource aimDark}" />
</Grid>
```

**The Problem:**

First my `Content` in the button doesn't appear, in fact there isn't text been render in my button.

And I don't know how to change only the border color in the Hover Event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `ContentPresenter` to make the content of the button appear.

Also if you define a name in `ControlTemplate>Border` you can modify it when a action is trigger like this:

```
<Style x:Key="mylayout" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,0" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#949494" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="the_gradient" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border CornerRadius="4" BorderBrush="#000000" BorderThickness="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Name="border">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#e9eceb" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `ControlTemplate` you should specify `ContentPresenter` to display the `Content` of a `Button`.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="aimDark">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,0" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#0e0e0e" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border
                    CornerRadius="4"
                    BorderBrush="#000000"
                    BorderThickness="1">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="#006d23" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#006d23" Offset="0.05" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#00c741" Offset="0.45" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#00c741" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>                                
                        </Border.Background>
                        <RenderOptions.EdgeMode>Aliased</RenderOptions.EdgeMode>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

The template that you created does not have a `ContentPresenter`, and that's required in order to show the content (text or other). I suggest you start from the [default Button template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328(v=vs.100).aspx) and make changes as you need.